# Truffle: How to test for inheritance

Tags: truffle, inheritance

I have a Contract `B` which should inherit from contract `A`.

Using Truffle, how can I test that this is indeed the case?

Comment: You can try calling a function A has and B doesn't have, if it succeeds.. High probability it inherits A.